# Struts 1: form can read bean value but on submit does not write in it

Tags: java, jsp, struts, actionform

Hello dear folks of stack overflow.
I encountered a problem recently in my Struts application.
I have a jsp which displays some bean value correctly (i paste only relevant part of the code, i simplified to the extreme):

```
<table>
    <logic:iterate name="bean" property="list1" id="listItem">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <html:checkbox name="listItem" property="selected">
            </html:checkbox>
        </td>
    </logic:iterate>
</table>
```

My bean has a list1 property with its getter and setter

```
private List<RandomObject> list1;

public List getList1() {
    return list1;
    }


public void setList1(List list1) {
    this.list1=list1;
    }
```

and my sub-bean  has a selected property:

```
private boolean selected;
public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
```

Now, when enter this jsp, the values i get are correct, ie: if my mapped object in DB was at selected=true, the checkbox is checked. What i dont get is how do i save the changes i make in this form. When i submit, all the changes are lost. This is pure struts related, because in debug when i enter the StrutsAction linked to submit, the ActionForm i get has already lost all interesting values. Also i feel like it has to do with the fact that the value i want to retain isn't directly stored on the main bean, but rather is a property of a sub-bean, because on the same page there are a lot of other properties directly on the main bean that i have no trouble saving.

What did i miss ?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably declaring incorrect `name` attributes in the rendered HTML. If you look at the generated source code for your page it probably looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selected" ...>
```

which would look for a `selected` field in your form bean class.

If you're using a collection that's a field in your form bean you want to be using the `<nested:form>`, `<nested:iterate>` and `<nested:checkbox` Struts tags, not the `<html:form>,``and`` ones. So it would then look like this:

```
<nested:form action="foo">
...

    <nested:iterate property="list1" id="listItem">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <nested:checkbox property="selected">
            </nested:checkbox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </nested:iterate>

...
</nested:form>
```

Note that I've removed the `name` attributes from the Struts tags, because they're not needed (in my experience they actually cause all kinds of problems - if you use `<nested:*>` tags don't use a `name` attribute). In the case of the `<nested:iterate>` the level of nesting is the form bean itself, so it knows that it needs to look for the `list1` property in the form bean.

That tag creates its own nesting level, so the `<nested:checkbox` knows that it needs to look for the `selected` property of the current element in the iteration.

The rendered HTML will look something like this (for the first element):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="list1[0].selected" ...>
```

which means the `selected` field of the first element (index 0) in the collection referenced by the `list1` field of your form bean.

And, of course, you'll need to make sure that you're using a session-scoped form bean, rather than a request-scoped one.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i had to put the name attribute into the iterate otherwise it gives me error(cannot find property into any bean...)

I resolved deleting the attribute name into the checkbox: it seems it create a new object at page scope that is not connected with the form.

This is my code:

```
<nested:iterate id="apertura" type="it.puglia.innova.view.actionform.AperturaForm" indexId="index"  name="strutturaRuraleForm"  property="listAperturaForm">
     <nested:checkbox styleId="checkbox_${index}" property="flagContinuato" onchange="changeOrarioContinuato(${index})"/>
```

that's it :-) didn't need to change html:form to nested too.

Bye